# NixOS list all possible configuration options

Tags: nixos

I started using NixOS a few days ago. It seems like there is a configuration option for everything, e.g. `hardware.opengl.driSupport32Bit` or `system.copySystemConfiguration`.

But the question is: can I see all options which are available? To give a few examples:

- How should I know what desktopManagers are available other than the "kde4", "kde5" and "gnome3"?
- What synaptics options can I use, other than `accelFactor` and `twoFingerScroll`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can search them at http://nixos.org/nixos/options.html or get the whole list at http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/options.html.

It's also possible to get the list at `man configuration.nix`

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I didn't find this before :facepalm

Comment: For the record, it is also possible to see the options via `man configuration.nix`.

Answer (score 3):

there is also:

- nix-repl
- nixos-option

both are very powerfull tools to query the system's configuration.

finally, if you want to use nixos options offline, you should have a look at this:

https://lastlog.de/blog/posts/nix-assistant.html